# Any idea why Route paths with multiple "/"s lose their styling in React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, styling, react-router-dom

I'm using React 16.8.4 and React-Router-Dom 5.0.0 to build a web app. I'm using scripts in the index.html file to import the styling for the React components, as opposed to having individual css files imported into each component (I mention this because I have a feeling it's part of the problem). All of the paths with single parameters work perfectly, but whenever I try to create a path with an additional, optional parameter, the components lose their styling. Below is the App class with the Routes. The "/classes/:class_id" Route is the problematic one.

```
import React, { Fragment, Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import SignUp from "./components/general_components/SignUp";
import Login from "./components/general_components/Login";
import ShopClasses from "./components/ShopClassesComponents/ShopClasses";
import Home from "./components/general_components/Home";
import Profile from "./components/profile_components/Profile";
import Toolbar from "./components/Toolbar";
import ClassInfo from "./components/ShopClassesComponents/ClassInfo";
import Footer from "./components/general_components/Footer";
import ContactUs from "./components/general_components/ContactUs";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link} from "react-router-dom";
import Route from "react-router-dom/Route"
import About from './components/about_components/About'


class App extends Component {
  state = {
    home: true
  };

  render() {

    return (
      <Router>
        <React.Fragment>
          <Toolbar />
          <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Home}/>
          <Route path="/classes" component={ShopClasses}/>
          <Route path="/classes/:class_id"  exact={true} component={ClassInfo}/>
          <Route path="/about" exact={true} component={About}/>
          <Route path="/signup" exact={true} component={SignUp}/>
          <Route path="/login" exact={true} component={Login}/>
          <Route path="/profile" exact={true} component={Profile}/>
          <Route path="/contact" exact={true} component={ContactUs}/>
          <Footer />
        </React.Fragment>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

I've tried creating other routes with multiple parameters to the same effect. It's not just that the component that is being rendered loses it's style, but also that the unconditionally rendered Toolbar and Footer lose their styling also. I've tried using the exact and strict props, but neither changed the rendering. Like I said above, I would imagine this has something to do with the scripts not being loaded, but I still see them in the HTML.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated, and I hope this isn't a dumb question.

Comment: so did you or did you not try importing individual css files to the ClassInfo component?

Comment: I did originally, then tried without. Both ways result in the Toolbar and Footer losing their styling.

Comment: can please share your code ?

Comment: I edited the post to include all of the imports. But that's all the source code for the file. Again, each other route and component works perfectly. Only when I add multiple routing parameters does the styling break.